I installed Ubuntu 24.04 with the 6.8.0.35-generic kernel and the BusyBox message appears
I do not know what to do. When I enter with kernel 6.5.0.41 it normally enters the initial screen. What went wrong?
System Details Report

Report details

Date generated:                              2024-06-21 09:55:59

Hardware Information:

Hardware Model:                              ASUSTeK Computer INC. Rampage III Extreme
Memory:                                      12,0 GiB
Processor:                                   Intel® Core™ i7 930  × 8
Graphics:                                    AMD Radeon™ RX 580 Series
Disk Capacity:                               1,2 TB

Software Information:

Firmware Version:                            0901
OS Name:                                     Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
OS Build:                                    (null)
OS Type:                                     64-bit
GNOME Version:                               46
Windowing System:                            X11
Kernel Version:                              Linux 6.5.0-41-generic

osz@osni-ubuntu:~$ apt list linux-image-generic
Listing... Done
linux-image-generic/noble-updates,noble-security,now 6.8.0-35.35 amd64 [installed,automatic]
N: There is 1 additional version. Please use the '-a' switch to see it
osz@osni-ubuntu:~$ apt list linux-image-generic -a
Listing... Done
linux-image-generic/noble-updates,noble-security,now 6.8.0-35.35 amd64 [installed,automatic]
linux-image-generic/noble 6.8.0-31.31 amd64


Continue to use 6.5.0.41, keep updating Ubuntu regularly, and most likely, the next kernel update in 6.8.x will fix the issue.

Undo what you did.

I managed to solve the problem via an answer I read in a case that occurred on an old Ubuntu distribution:

Enter reboot in the prompt
Go to BIOS setup
Go to SATA Configuration
Change to AHCI
save and restart.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/589899/missing-modules-cat-proc-modules-ls-dev-and-uuid-doesnt-exist-in-busybox
